# Does $f \in C^2$ imply $\int [f'(x)]^2 dx < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I'm looking at a handout from my teacher that says in the question that $f \in C^2$.  $f(x)$ maps $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$.  Later on it says $\int [f'(x)]^2dx < \infty$.  I'm not able to see how one follows from the other.  I know if $f \in C^2$ then $f \in C^1$ and that means that $f'(x) < \infty$.  But that doesn't necessarily mean that the integral of the derivative squared is finite, right?

If you could please cite theorems that help with understanding this, that would be useful.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any context on the domain?

Comment: $f(x)$ maps $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function which is continuous on a compact interval $[a,b]$ is integrable on such interval (which means that its integral over $[a,b]$ is finite). So 
if $f\in C^2([a,b])$ then $f'^2\in C([a,b])$ and 
$$\int_a^b (f'(x))^2\,dx <\infty.$$
The above property can be false for improper integrals: for example $f(x)=x^2\in C^2([0,+\infty))$ or $f(x)=1/x\in C^2((0,1])$, but the integral of $f'^2$ is divergent on such intervals.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x, x \in \mathbb  R$ is a counterexample. If your function is defined on a compact interval $[a,b]$ the use the fact that any continuous function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  if the integral is on a cmpact interval, then is it true?  (look at RobetrZ's answer)

Comment: @nundo $(f')^{2}$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and hence it is integrable.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  So, maybe this is a trivial question but in general, if a function is in $C^1$ then is it continuous?  that's what you seem to be implying

Comment: @nundo The usual definition of a $C^{k}$ function is a function which has continuous derivatives up to order $k$.